# Array of values

Tags: javascript, mongodb

For example I have `n` doc in MongoDB collection

```
Films = new Mongo.Collection('films');
Film.insert({name: 'name n', actor: 'John'}); // *n
```

And I want to show array with `only name` values

```
var names = ['name 1', 'name 2',..,'name n'];
```

Any idea how to do it ?

And guys , ols write in comments correct title value of my question, to help other guys to find it, thx :)

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33118097/edit) your question to add sample document with the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provided any criteria for grouping `name` as an array.
You can use following query to get all names:

```
db.collection.distinct("name")
```

OR you can use MongoDB's [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) to get all `name` by grouping them with some condition, if required. The query will be like following:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $group: {
    _id: null, //add condition if require
    name: {
        $push: "$name"
    }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
    name: 1,
    _id: 0
    }
})
```

If you want only distinct `name` then replace `$push` with `$addToSet`.